# compare the intervalue in a textbox

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

```
if (intval(($text) > 5)) {
  header("Location: http://a???.php");
} else {
  header("Location: http://a???/show.php");
}
```

I want to compare the int value entered in `$test` and if it is greater than 5 (12345,12321,22222). But it doesn't work

```
if (intval(($text) > 5)) //compare the value entered to see if it's greater than 5
```

Comment: what values are used for $test

Comment: In your question you mention $test, in your code $text ... Typo?

Comment: I guess you have a mistake: it should be `if (intval($test) > 5) { ... }`

Comment: You don't need `intval()`, PHP converts automatically when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert to int first, then compare.  Try:

```
if(intval($text) > 5) ...
```

Comment: pls how do i conver to int?

Comment: just update your if statement with code above.  You almost had it, just needed to correct your parantheses.

Comment: ok thanks very much, if i want the intval to be equal to 5, how do i do it ??? 'if(intval($text)==5)' is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You have some extras parentheses in your `if` statement.

```php
if (intval($text) > 5) // That should do it
```